# How to run multiple training tasks on different GPUs?

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have 2 GPUs on my server which I want to run different training tasks on them.

On the first task, trying to force the Tensorflow to use only one GPU, I added the following code at the top of my script :

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'
```

After running the first task, when I try to run the second task on the other GPU, (with the same 2 lines of code) I get the error ***`"No device GPU:1"`***.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *"What is the problem?"*

The system needs to see the cards - validate the current state of the server, using the call to ( `hwloc`-tool ) **`lstopo`** :

```
$ lstopo --only osdev
GPU L#0 "card1"
GPU L#1 "renderD128"
GPU L#2 "card2"
GPU L#3 "renderD129"
GPU L#4 "card3"
GPU L#5 "renderD130"
GPU L#6 "card0"
GPU L#7 "controlD64"
Block(Disk) L#8 "sda"
Block(Disk) L#9 "sdb"
Net L#10 "eth0"
Net L#11 "eno1"
GPU L#12 "card4"
GPU L#13 "renderD131"
GPU L#14 "card5"
GPU L#15 "renderD132"
```

If showing more than just an above mentioned `card0`, proceed with proper naming / `id#`-s
and
be sure to *set it **before** doing any other `import`-s, like that of `pycuda` and `tensorflow`.*

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '1'   # MUST PRECEDE ANY IMPORT-s
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
import pycuda     as pyCUDA
import tensorflow as tf
...
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: When I set visible devices in first process to see only GPU:0 and print available gpus on the other process it see GPU:0 which I think is GPU:1

Comment: Damned enforced (un)visibility re-indexing :o)